# UWP: How to render Multi Column WebView instead of having vertical scroll bar

Tags: css, xaml, webview, uwp

Instead of having a scroll bar I want to move it to the next column, Is it possible with WebView control?

See the image below:

[image]

The content with "Red Box" I want to move it to the second column.

XAML CODE:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="500" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row="0" />
<WebView Grid.Row="1" Width="410" local:WebViewProperties.HtmlString="{Binding Description}"></WebView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to render Multi Column WebView instead of having vertical scroll bar

[`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) can not render your HTML content to multi columns. And also this should not be done by the `WebView` control. You should be able to set the HTML content to multi columns by CSS style. For example,the following `newspaper` div is showed as two columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .newspaper {
            -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
            column-count: 2; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>
    <div class="newspaper">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

More details please reference [CSS3 Multiple Columns](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp). Updating the HTML layout to what you want by HTML elements or CSS style then render them.